# I have a small problem with a border on a text input

Tags: html, css

I have this coded, but that border still there

```
.input{
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: rgb(0, 91, 65);
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

.input::placeholder{
    color: rgb(0, 91, 65);
}

.input:hover{
    cursor: text;
}
```

The border that I want to get rid off

[image: The border that I whant to get rid off]

I tried most of the things, but with no change, the `background: trasparent;` was the only thing that change something of this border but while not on focus

Comment: I can't see any border in that image.

Comment: Its a bellow border in black

Comment: please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you.

Comment: If its on a focused input, you should add style with :focus pseudo class. And maybe it's not a border but an outline. So try: `.input:focus, .input:focus-visible { outline: none; border: 0; }`

Comment: Is not that either

Comment: I've tried to make a minimal example, but there is something to do with other things

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the default html style you should indicate the focused element in some other way.

```css
input, input:focus, input:focus-visible {
 border:0;
 outline:0;
 filter: drop-shadow(30px 10px 4px #4444dd); 
 }
 input:focus-visible {
 filter: drop-shadow(33px 13px 4px #4444dd); 
 }
```

```html
  <input name=firstname placeholder="firstname" value="Nada es lo"/>
  <input name=lastname placeholder="lastname" value="que parece"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just remade the page and the line was gone, I cannot tell what was the specific thing that made that line appear, but It's done

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).